# What is the use of the jar without dependencies Maven created for me?

Tags: java, maven

I am using Maven and my configuration (which is most likely the default) produces this:

[image: image description]

That means my compiled code is **4%** of the file. Largest inflation was caused by the GitHub API library - I am strongly considering that I'll just drop it.

But my question is about the small file, not the big one. Maven creates it for a reason right? Could I maybe somehow distribute it and have it work on clients' computers? **Why does it exist** and **what useful can be done with that**?

Comment: What do you mean by "somehow distribute it and have it work on clients' computers"?

Comment: That means people will download it, those 500kb and it will work. Is there something unclear on what software distribution means? Or is it the *to work* part?

Comment: You can use it as a library in other code. Maven will work out the dependencies and download them automatically. If you want to _run_ the file (without Maven) you have to distribute the **full** code - i.e. with dependencies.

Comment: that jar **must** be available at runtime for your code to work. It does not have to be bundled in with your code in the jar. Leaving it external greatly increases the complexity of running your code and having it break in the future increasing maintenance incidents. See the duplicate for how to reference external dependencies from your jar.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson not sure it's a duplicate. The OP _has_ an uberjar already; the question is _can the small jar be used instead_.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I read the post you call duplicate before and I am unsure based on what you call it a duplicate. I am obviously not asking how to create the file when it's staring right at me. I ask you to further specify which part of the answers there answers my question, as it seems to me they do not address my concern - **what is the purpose/use** of the file without dependencies - at all.

Comment: The duplicate asks the exact same question *how do I create/distribute a .jar  without dependencies*.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson This doesn't seem like a duplicate at all to me, I'm very confused by the close. OP clearly knows how to create a jar that includes its dependencies --- he's asking how a jar without dependencies can be useful (given that his program needs those dependencies to run). His example depends on the fact that he has already created a jar that includes its dependencies.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I do not only ask how to distribute but generally what to do with it. I even highlighted the important points. I will modify the title slightly to clear your confusion.

Comment: The duplicate explains what the one without the dependencies is, this question makes no sense if it is just why is there one without dependencies. If so, **it is because you can distribute it that way if you want and the duplicate explains how you do this and why**.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson The question is --- "if my code depends on X library to run, why would I ever want to distribute a jar that doesn't include X library?" The linked question just explains how to bundle dependencies into one jar, it doesn't address this question at all.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I've reopened the question as I feel it didn't answer about the use of the JAR without dependencies and why it is there to begin with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given your question, your Maven project is most likely a `jar` project that uses the `maven-assembly-plugin` to generate an uber-jar. In your output, there are 2 different files that are the result of 2 completely different process.

---

`autoclient-3.0.jar` is what's called the main artifact. This is the primary result of the Maven build. It consists of the compiled classes in your project alone, packaged into a `jar` by the `maven-jar-plugin`. You have this file because your project has the `jar` packaging. In Maven, the `jar` packaging [automatically bind goals to build phases of the default lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Packaging): among others, it includes an invocation of the `jar:jar` goal, which creates this main JAR. But you have to realize that this JAR only contains *your* classes. If you try to run the code, it will probably fail because the dependencies won't be there. What's its purpose if you can't run it then? Well, its purpose is to serve as a library for other projects, not as executable code.

Take, for example, a utility library that you would like to create: this library is not intended to be ran directly, it's intended to be used as a dependency for another project which will be executable. With the notion of [transitive dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies), Maven will automatically include in the buildpath of the other project your library and all its transitive dependencies. As such, your library does not need to embed its dependencies directly: they will be resolved correctly during the build of the other project.

---

`autoclient-3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar` is what's called an additional artifact. [`jar-with-dependencies` is a classifier](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploying-with-classifiers.html)  that is used to distinguish this artifact from the main one. It is the result of the execution of the [`maven-assembly-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) with the [predefined `jar-with-dependencies` descriptor file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies). This artifact consists of the compiled classes of your project *and* all the direct and transitive dependencies of your project. An uber-jar (or fat jar) is really that: it aggregates all the dependencies and your code inside one big jar. The advantage is that you don't need to distribute separately the dependencies, they are already included in the JAR. But do note that its purpose is not to serve as a library, it is to be used as executable code.

Note that for a single project, it could make sense to keep both JAR: one intended to be used as a library (the main JAR) and the other intended to be used as runnable JAR.